# Have tex_file_2 continue counter from tex_file_1

Tags: hyperref, counters, setcounter, xr-hyper

I have tex_file_1 (the main text) with numbered corollaries, propositions, etc. In tex_file_2 (the appendix) I want the numbering to pick up where tex_file_1 left off. So if the last proposition in tex_file_1 is Proposition 4, I want the first proposition in tex_file_2 to be Proposition 5.

I'm linking the two as follows, in their respective preambles:

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\externaldocument{tex_file_2} % this is in tex_file_1, and vice-versa
```

I could hard-code it, e.g. in tex_file_2 I could just put `\setcounter{prop}{5}`. But I'd rather have it be flexible, so that if I change the number of propositions in tex_file_1, then the numbering in tex_file_2 adjusts automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would meet this requirement using `\include` which needs to save all counter values so it can "skip over" non-included files. But here you can borrow some `\include` internals and save the list to a file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{aa}

\begin{figure}
\caption{fff}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
  111
\end{equation}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\savenums
\immediate\openout\savenums=\jobname.num
{\let\@partaux\savenums\let\@elt\@wckptelt \cl@@ckpt}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

When run, this will write a file `filename.num` that looks like

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{equation}{1}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

saving the value of every declared latex counter.

So your second file then just needs `\input{filename.num}` to pick up from here

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!